# Countifs support excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Can anyone please tell me what I need to add to the formula in the picture.

Column G tells me the type of membership. 
I need to count the number of connections sales sold that count when 12DM or DPP is selected in column G. My formula works for 12DM but when I try to add in to count both, I cannot get it to work.

Thank you,

[image]

Comment: `=COUNTIFS(..."=12DM")+COUNTIFS(..."=DPP")` would work

Comment: Thanks Alex, so would this count ALL sales that were connections that also have the drop down DPP or 12DM in column G?

Comment: It does do something closer to the equation but doesn't add quite correctly when tested. Thank you though, one step closer

Comment: Thank you, amazing got that to work - you absolute legend :)

Answer (score -1):

**Some common issues with COUNTIFS:**

*Formula returns #VALUE! error when,*

- The criteria range arrays are not equal in 
  length.
- If criteria are text and are longer than 255 
  characters.

Every additional range should have same dimension as the **criteria range1**, although it's necessary that they aren’t adjacent to each other.

---

*In your case, I would like to suggest following formula:*

```
=SUM(COUNTIFS(G4:G403,{"12DM","DPP"}), COUNTIFS(B4:B403,"1st"),COUNTIFS(I4:I403,"Connection"))
```

---

```
=SUMPRODUCT((G4:G403="12DM")+(G4:G403="DPP")+(B4:B403="1st")+(I4:I403="Connection"))
```

*You may adjust cell references as needed.*

Comment: -1. Has nothing to do with the question being asked.

Comment: @AlexM,, thanks for valuable observation,, could you suggest what went wrong !! **This is what OP is struggling with ,, *I need to count the number of connections sales sold that count when 12DM or DPP is selected in column G*.** And both of my suggested formula shows that how to use two criteria.